# List / database of valid addresses for geolocation / geospatial testing

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm running some geospatial tests to demonstrate use of the MongoDB geo APIs. The problem is that I don't have a list of valid addresses with which I can test.

The idea is to query the latitude and longitude through Bing Maps as my sample application is a job search website where the locations I will be indexing to query against would be entered as listing for new job opportunities and would be entered using addresses rather than latitude and longitude coordinates.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I don't suspect Microsoft provides a list of fake locations that will register to valid lat/long coordinates on Bing (for this exact purpose or similar), but if they do...that would be equally acceptable.

FWIW, I did thoroughly check Microsoft's documentation and found nothing on this.

---

Alternatively, I could just query common places like Starbuck's or POI's (probably what I'll end up doing), but it would be nicer if there were a testing mode where you could use addresses that would register with Bing. Microsoft, in case you happen to subscribe to Stack Overflow tags, I would post this suggestion on the Bing community forums but there is no way to post an answer or question there, please fix this.

Comment: Re: your last point. I'm not Microsoft, but the Bing Maps MSDN forums are at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vemapcontroldev/threads - there's a link to "Ask a question" at the top of the page.However, I would agree with you that they don't make available a list of testing addresses - I'd just use a list of addresses of popular company stores - Starbucks, McDonalds, Subway etc. POIs are less likely to have regular street addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the link! ...try going to the documentation for the AJAX or REST control and click the links to go to the forums :)

Answer (score 0):

Decided just to use the Bing Maps API to query some popular companies although this is not ideal.